# Restricting storage files access via url

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a folder in storage (app/public) which is being used for file upload (files are being uploaded and obtained via laravel's storage). 
Direct access to directories inside that folder are forbidden, but the files inside that directories are accessible directly via path
(ex. http://test:8888/storage/documents/1/user/1/files/index.html - numbers are ids in this case).

Is it possible to restrict access to a directory directly via url on a server, and allow it only to be embedded in iframe on this server? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: i dont think so since an iframe has an `src` and basically is just the client retrieving the resources from that url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use as an api route, so can restrict access with middleware in your route.php

Comment: i'm not sure that would be a solution, since the files need to be accessed directly via iframe's src attribute.